# Given the breadth of Nintex in the SharePoint community, why is it considered "Off topic"?

Tags: discussion

I ran across [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/148295/use-display-name-in-workflow-variable-with-multiple-names-nintex) question this morning which holds (in my opinion) a relatively routine Nintex Workflow problem that I've come across a few times. I was hoping to provide an answer for the original poster but then couldn't as it had been closed as being off-topic.

Shouldn't we consider Nintex questions as within scope for this community? If not, why not as there certainly isn't any other StackExchange community for these questions to live and they certianly make no sense outside of a SharePoint scope.

Comment: There isn't a Stack Exchange community for this because there is a community supported and monitored by Nintex staff at their web site where you can talk about all of their product offerings. They offer support as part of the purchase, so that should be used.

Comment: Moreover, if we open up Nintex, then we could open up support for K2, AvePoint, Metalogix, and the list can go on and on.